# Getting error with prepared statement

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

Followed a video and what should work just fine instead is giving me an error. I get the WHOOPS error from !mysqli_stmt_prepare. Maybe there's something I've missed? The video had us remove the values in place of "?"s, but this had never worked for me, so I just put the $var back in. BTW: There are only special characters (apostrophes and quotes) inside of the personal statement when they form is submitted. I thought the statement would escape those no problem. Thanks.

```
<?php

    header('Refresh:3; url=/Collaborate/');

$link = mysqli_connect("*****","*****","*****", "*****");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
 }

    $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];

    $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];

    $Website = $_POST['Website'];

    $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];

    $Email = $_POST['Email'];

    $Interests1 = $_POST['Int1'];

    $Interests2 = $_POST['Int2'];

    $Interests3 = $_POST['Int3'];

    $PersonalStatement = $_POST['PersonalStatement'];

    // BAD ESCAPE. BAD!
        // array_walk_recursive($link, $_POST, 'mysqli_real_escape_string' );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO User(Fname, Lname, Website, Phone, Email, Interest1, Interest2, Interest3, PersonalStatement) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "sssssssss", $sql)) {
        echo "WHOOPS!";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $Fname, $Lname, $Website, $Phone, $Email, $Interests1, $Interests2, $Interests3, $PersonalStatement);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "<h2>We got you $Fname!</h2>";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You're creating your SQL statement in such a way that you're simply plugging the plaintext directly into the statement, plaintext which is susceptible to altering by the person making the request. This means you're both a) susceptible to SQL injection attacks, and b) unable to correctly process any text that contains a single quote. Please work on getting proper prepared SQL statements working via binding parameters. If you have difficulty getting this working, please post another question with what you have after trying that route. Trust me, it will save you some major headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your sql string values with `?` . In `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` - you need the second argument to be - `"sssssssss"`

Comment: I've replaced every '$***' with just ? and added the "sssssssss". I still get the error. Is there anything else I need to be checking?

Comment: Replace with - `$sql = "INSERT INTO User(Fname, Lname, Website, Phone, Email, Interest1, Interest2, Interest3, PersonalStatement) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";`

Comment: After - `echo "WHOOPS!";` - add - `echo "<br/>".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);`

Comment: There's no error displaying. It still only shows whoops.

Comment: I wasn't sure what pastebin was, but now I do. What I posted here is all of the code. I don't know what else you want me to include. I also don't know if this is a phpmyadmin thing perhaps with how I set up the database. Of the nine entries, the three interest values are ENUM with a list. Is this different than string? Forgive my lack of understanding. I've been building a website the last 3 weeks, learning tons of code and a lot of the terminology slips past me. Thank you!

Comment: Enum has the same approach. In - `mysqli_stmt_prepare()` - you added `'sssss'`, remove that it's for - `mysqli_stmt_bind_param(....)`

Comment: YAAAHOOOO! You did it Mr. Blue! Thank you! Probably staring at my computer screen for 16 hours doesn't help me locate where to put stuff!